# Variable context in jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, namespaces

Hellp

I have a JS module which updates some html every second. 
example

```
helpers.getStepList('.update-time-js',i).html('text');
```

This function is called all the time to get the li element.

```
    getStepList: function(element, index) {
        var stepList = $('.step-list > li');
        return $(element, stepList).eq(index -1);
    }
```

Im not sure this is good for the performance . Is there a better way to get the stepList elements ?

If I include

```
var stepList = $('.step-list > li');
```

in the same file as the html is updated it will run every second too...

Comment: `$(element, stepList)` doesn't seem to make sense to me. The second argument to jQuery should be a selector, not a collection.

Comment: So I suspect what you want is `$(element, '.step-list > li')`.

Comment: @Barmar, the stepList is a selector, that is a variable for `'step-list > li'`. :)

Comment: It's not a selector when you do `stepList = $('.step-list > li')`, it's the collection that results from that selector.

Comment: @Barmar - calling `$()` with [`$( selector [, context ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) is fine, where the second argument is a "DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context".

Comment: Ah, never mind, I was mistakenly thinking it was `$(context, selector)`

Comment: The problem is im calling the var steplist for each li I need to modify. I don't know if this is bad for performance...

Comment: You can also call it directly in the selector li:eq(index)